# How can I use a bounding sphere for intersection?

Tags: bounding-spheres

How can I use a bounding sphere for intersection, like on a statue? Would I use the radius to detect intersection?

Comment: Hi Terry, could you give us some more details. Are you attempting to do this in some specific code? Or are you more interested in just how the general mathematics works?

Comment: Two spheres intersect if the distance between them is less than the sum of their radii. I'm not entirely sure that's what your question is asking though. Most collisions in games are done with the SAT or GJK algorithm.

Comment: Yes, as @AndrewWilson said, use distance to check for intersection. For instance, if you're intersecting with a point, check if the distance from the point to the center of the sphere is less than or equal to the radius of the sphere.